# Greying out a button from code-behind does not work in IE

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer, code-behind

I have two drop down lists on a page. The behavior is as follows:

1. select something in list 1
2. list 2 is enabled
3. select something in list 2
4. button is enabled

I am doing the above with autopostback enabled on the drop down lists. To toggle the button I use the code below:

```
if (ddlAvailablePrograms.SelectedValue != string.Empty)
{
     careerInfoLearnMoreSubmit.Enabled = true;
     careerInfoLearnMoreSubmit.Style.Remove("opacity");
     careerInfoLearnMoreSubmit.Style.Add("opacity", "1.0;");
}
else
{
     careerInfoLearnMoreSubmit.Enabled = false;
     careerInfoLearnMoreSubmit.Style.Remove("opacity");
     careerInfoLearnMoreSubmit.Style.Add("opacity", "0.5;");
}
```

This works fine in Firefox but in IE as soon as I make a selection in the first drop down list the button looses its greyed out style.

Any suggestions how to fix this in IE?

Thanks,
b3n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **opacity** CSS style has known issues with Internet Explorer.

Try adding this to your CSS stylesheet, and instead of adding an inline style, add a class:

```
.opaque {
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; 
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);                  
}
```

Order has to be exactly like above.

This technique is shown/used here: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/opacity.html

Also, i have heard using jQuery to apply the opacity is ideal, because jQuery handles all cross-browser issues. Is that an option?

Comment: Thanks using the classes worked. The issue was that the style was initially set using javascript. After the first drop down list caused an update panel reload the style was lost for IE as the inline style that I used did not work. I modified my code to check if the browser is IE and if so it uses the classes now, if its firefox I use the old inline style. Works great.